# Citing an encyclopedia in another language

Tags: citations

I would like to cite the following page from an encyclopedia

https://encyclopediasindhiana.org/article.php?Dflt=%D8%A7%D9%BD%D9%8A+%DA%8F%DA%AA%D8%B1

but I am unsure about how to do it. I can't even read the original, I am actually using Google Translate.

Comment: Is this something that isn't possible to find in a language you know? Relying on Google Translate seems iffy.

Comment: @BryanKrause I can't seem to find this anywhere else (except an song posted Youtube). I have gotten a Sindhi-speaking friend to translate it, but you would I actually cite this?

Answer (score 3):

You just cite it as you usually would cite an encyclopedia article but using transliteration from Arabic (?) script to Latin script and identifying that the original is in Sindhi. It would be best to get help from someone who knows either Sindhi or has more familiarity with the Arabic script.

Comment: It is in Sindhi, not Arabic